# How does this theorem of Robertson, Seymour, and Thomas imply Hadwiger's conjecture for $k$ = 6?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

The result in question is

*Theorem* Every 6-contraction-critical graph $G \neq K_6$ has a vertex $x$ such that $G-x$ is planar.

The article I'm reading ("A Survey of Hadwiger's Conjecture" by Bjarne Toft) points out that $G-x$ is four-colorable (of course), and then that $G$ is at most 5-colorable. I don't have access to other materials on this result at the moment, and I'm not sure I trust my intuition, which is as follows:

A graph is defined as being 6-contraction-critical if it is 6-chromatic and every minor of the graph is $n$-chromatic for some $n<6$. It seems to me that the theorem together with Toft's observation implies that no 6-contraction-critical graph exists except for $K_6$, but then I can't see how to go from there to Hadwiger's conjecture for $k = 6$, which states that every 6-chromatic graph contains a $K_6$ minor. Moreover, as already mentioned, I'm not sure if the implication I cited just a moment ago is correct--it seems kind of radical, but my ability to imagine counterexamples seems tragically limited.

So, am I on the right track? If I am, how do I fill in the gap, and if I'm not, how do I get on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a counterexample  to Hadwiger's conjecture for $k=6$ with the smallest number of vertices, then $G$ is $6$-contraction-critical. Since if it is not, then if you contract an edge of $G$ and obtain a graph $H$ with a chromatic number $6$ then $H$ must have $K_6$-minor since $H$ is smaller than the minimum conterexample.

Comment: Thank you. So if I'm understanding you correctly, the rest of the argument proceeds as:
If $G$ is a smallest counterexample to HC6, $G$ is in fact 5-chromatic by the reasoning mentioned in my question, a contradiction. Hence, no smallest counterexample to HC6 exists and hence no counterexample exists.
Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.